# Look for a particular constraint in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

One of my friend created a table in mySQl, how can I check whether he applied  a particular constraint on a column name or not.

In my case, I want to verify whether he applied a `CHECK` constraint on the column `CHG_HOUR` or not? The query `DESC JOB` does not help me with the 'CHECK' constraint.

```
mysql> desc JOB;
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| JOB_CODE     | char(3)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| JOB_CLASS    | char(30)      | YES  |     | NA      |       |
| CHG_HOUR     | decimal(12,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| OVERTIME_CHG | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.0.16?

Comment: no, it shows `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper` on Ubuntu 18.04 when I entered `mysql --version` in terminal.

Comment: Then you're not using MySQL 8, in which case you can't use a check constraint.  Your only option then would be to use a trigger.

Comment: and what about other constraints, is there any way to check what all constraints are applied in my table?

Comment: Show create <table>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: he didn't.

MySQL doesn't support check constraints until [8.0.16](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) which, at the time of writing, does not seen to be even released.